# Launch specific URL in an ASP.NET Core app in VSCode when running the app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

(Running on a Mac if that matters.)

In Visual Studio you use this method to launch a specific URL when running or debugging your ASP.NET Core project. The launchUrl property is used. This is a sample launchSettings.json file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "customstartupurlgoeshere/?id=theanswertotheuniverse",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

What's the analog in VS Code? I read that VS Code ignores the launchSettings.json file.

Answer (score 11):

You can update your `launch.json`. Add the `serverReadyAction`'s `uriFormat`; e.g.,

```
 "serverReadyAction": {
     "action": "openExternally",
     "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+https://localhost:([0-9]+)",
     "uriFormat": "https://localhost:%s/swagger"
 },
```

Note that in the example we capture the port number specifically as that is used where the first `%s` is in the `uriFormat`.

Comment: For .NET Core 6 just add  "uriFormat": "%s/swagger" works.

Comment: I haven't been in C# for a while, and I haven't set up a completely brand new app in a while, thanks for this! [serverReadyAction docs](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/debugger-launchjson.md#starting-a-web-browser) -- It looks like this was originally a preview feature around the Feb 2019 release. I don't normally auto-launch a browser for apis, but it's definitely useful in some cases. .NET will still use the launchSettings.json for the app based on some rules, or you can specify a `launchSettingsProfile` at the root of the launch launch.json config for ports, etc.

Answer (score 7):

VSCode takes the `.vscode/launch.json` configuration when launching a program.

> *The launchUrl property is used .... What's the analog in VS Code?*

You can change the `args` parameter to accept an argument of `--urls`. For example, if you want to make the kestrel listen on `6001`/`6000`:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/App.dll",
        "args": ["--urls","https://localhost:6001;http://localhost:6000"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question the OP was asking, this answer is how you set the equivalent of `launchSettings.json`'s `applicationUrl` property not `launchUrl`

Comment: As of "args", thanks so much! Finally I was able to make the app listen on something different than 5000/5001. 
Everything is very well berried in tons of other (irrelevant) information. Welcome back to the Linux style! This threw me back decades...

Answer (score 5):

For .NET core 6, 7 and 8, edit .vscode/launch.json and add `"uriFormat": "%s/swagger"` like this :

```json
"serverReadyAction": {
  "action": "openExternally",
  "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)",
  "uriFormat": "%s/swagger"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this and set correct path to the file.

```
"launchSettingsFilePath": "${workspaceFolder}/Properties/launchSettings.json",
```

Comment: It seems seems that the `launchUrl` property is not supported, so this approach doesnt do what OP is asking. [From the docs](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/7095cdad1549686d6786df18e36c2db0cf76b24c/debugger-launchjson.md#launchsettingsjson-support): *"Only `environmentVariables`, `applicationUrl` and `commandLineArgs` properties are supported"*