# Setting port for VS Code MVC Core using environment variables not working for port number

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to get VS Code to launch an asp.net mvc core website utilizing a specific port number.  I would like to set this via the VS Code launch.json, and NOT utilize the appsettings.json files.  I have referenced multiple websites that list a number of options, but none work other than using the appsettings.json file.  Setting "ASPNETCORE_URLS":"https://localhost:5050" does not work, nor do setting the arguments.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/WAPI.Foundation/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/WAPI.Foundation.dll",
        "args": [ ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/WAPI.Foundation",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)",
            "uriFormat": "index.html"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS":"https://localhost:5050"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
] }
```

I have referenced among others: [VSCode launch ASP.NET Core app on a specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949752/vscode-launch-asp-net-core-app-on-a-specific-port)

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to set the launch.json configuration command line "args" "--urls" property like so.  I did not modify the "env" variables as described in other posts.

```
"configurations": [
{
    "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
    ...
    "args": ["--urls","https://localhost:44304;http://localhost:6000"],
    "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
    },
    ...
}
```

]

I found the answer here: [Launch specific URL in an ASP.NET Core app in VSCode when running the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024379/launch-specific-url-in-an-asp-net-core-app-in-vscode-when-running-the-app).

Google searches on 'vs code setting port number' did not return this specific result, but search for 'vs code set url to run on' brought it right up.